# How to upload a file to a directory in Azure File Share

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Using `Azure Portal`, I'm trying to upload a file named `doc.txt` in a directory named `TestDir` in an [Azure File Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share) that I created. But the file always gets uploaded to the root directory as shown in the following steps:

[image]

Click on the above directory shows me the following:

[image]

Then I click on Upload button on the top bar to get the following:

[image]

Then I upload `doc.txt` file using the dialog shown on the left of the image below. But as you can see in the left pane below the `doc.txt` is uploaded outside the `TestDir`:

[image]

Comment: Actually, the image you uploaded shows it is in the `TestDir` folder

Comment: @ShiranDror Got it (thank you). I misunderstood the last image. I thought it's showing the `TestDir` and `doc.txt` under root folder. Your comment should be a response. If you like you can briefly explain your comment in a response; and Ill mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tou see in the last image, the image is uploaded inside the TestDir folder,

you could see the parent directory showing at the top as **`TestDir`**

[image]

Comment: Would you have a suggestion on [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3f3668ae-9f75-451e-9ec9-6b49f379146d/azure-handsonlabs-user-has-not-enough-permissions-to-perform-necessary-actions-described-in-the?forum=AzureMigrate) Azure related quest?

Comment: posted answer there